# How to solve Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string while returning data into view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Laravel controller code

```
public function switchInfo($prisw, $secsw){

    $cur_sw_pair_id = DB::table('sw_pairs')
        ->select('sw_pair_id')
        ->where('pri_sw','=',$prisw)
        ->where('sec_sw','=',$secsw)
        ->get();

    $infolist = DB::table('cust_sw_pair')
        ->select('interface','pri_sw_vlan','sec_sw_vlan','pri_sw_admin_status','sec_sw_admin_status','description')
        ->where('sw_pair_id', '=', $cur_sw_pair_id)
        ->get();

    return view('switchinfo.switchinfoview',compact('infolist'));

}
```

when this code executing it gives Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error. How can i solve this? How can i pass my infolist into switchinfoview view without getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pluck()` to get value of a column.

Your first query should like this:

```
$cur_sw_pair_id = DB::table('sw_pairs')
    ->where('pri_sw','=',$prisw)
    ->where('sec_sw','=',$secsw)
    ->pluck('sw_pairs');
```

Keep the second query as it is.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `->get()` returns a collection, which is a 0-indexed collection of results (rows) from the database. In your case, you want to be using the following query:

```
$cur_sw_pair_id = DB::table('sw_pairs')
    ->select('sw_pair_id')
    ->where('pri_sw','=',$prisw)
    ->where('sec_sw','=',$secsw)
    ->first();
```

And then accessing the property `sw_pair_id` of `$cur_sw_pair_id`, like so:

```
$infolist = DB::table('cust_sw_pair')
    ->select('interface','pri_sw_vlan','sec_sw_vlan','pri_sw_admin_status','sec_sw_admin_status','description')
    ->where('sw_pair_id', '=', $cur_sw_pair_id->sw_pair_id)
    ->first();
```

Then, in your view, you can access all the properties (anything in the `->select()` statement) of `$infolist` using `$infolist->PROPERTY_HERE`

Note that using `->first()` is essentially using the same as `->get();`, but you have to access the results of `->get()` using an index, so

```
$cur_sw_pair_id[0]->sw_pair_id
```

Hope that provides some insight for you.

Comment: i want to get all the details exist in the database table. not a single row